# net use /delete error 85

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I am trying to create a simple batch file that will allow me to add and remove network drives, but when I try to remove a drive i get error 85 "local device name is already in use".

When I type in `net use /delete G:` on its own in cmd window it works just fine

Any Help will be appreciated

Here are relevant pieces of code:

```
:remove
echo ---------------------------------------
echo Which drive would you like to remove?
echo.
echo 1. B: drive 
echo 2. G: drive 
echo 3. H: drive 
echo 4. I: drive 
echo 5. J: drive 
echo 6. N: drive 
echo 7. P: drive 
echo 8. V: drive 
echo. 
echo 0. Back
echo ---------------------------------------
set /p choice="Enter your choice: "
if "%choice%"=="1" goto remB
if "%choice%"=="2" goto remG
if "%choice%"=="3" goto remH
if "%choice%"=="4" goto remI
if "%choice%"=="5" goto remJ
if "%choice%"=="6" goto remN
if "%choice%"=="7" goto remP
if "%choice%"=="8" goto remV
if "%choice%"=="0" goto start
echo Invalid choice: %choice%
echo.
pause
cls
goto remove

:remB
cls
net use B: \delete
goto remove

:remG
cls
net use G: \delete
goto remove

:remH
cls
net use H: \delete
goto remove

:remI
cls
net use I: \delete
goto remove

:remJ
cls
net use J: \delete
goto remove

:remN
cls
net use N: \delete
goto remove

:remP
cls
net use P: \delete
goto remove

:remV
cls
net use V: \delete
goto remove
```

Comment: you're using `\delete` in your batch file, which is an invalid switch. Change it to `/delete`

Comment: Had a feeling it might be something silly, THANKS @MattWilliamson !